# Infinite Sum of Normals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If we sum a finite number of Normals, $\displaystyle \sum^n_{k=1} X_k \sim N(\sum^n_{k=1}\mu_k,\sum^n_{k=1}\sigma_k^2)$. Is this valid when we do an infinite sum, as long as $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\mu_k \text{ and }\sum^\infty_{k=1}\sigma_k^2$ converge, or do we need some extra conditions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the missing hypothesis that the random variables are **independent**, if every $X_k$ is normal $\mathcal N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)$ and if the series $\sum\limits_k\mu_k$ and $\sum\limits_k\sigma_k^2$ both converge then yes, the series $\sum\limits_kX_k$ converges in distribution.

Easiest approach: characteristic functions + Lévy's convergence theorem.

Comment: Then I am confused. What about a sequence $\{\sigma_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ that does not fulfil the necessary and sufficient Lindeberg condition? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition

Comment: @Martingalo The *central limit theorem* is about a sequence of averages, not a sequence of partial sums.

Comment: What about it? L condition becomes necessary only when $\sum\limits_k\sigma_k^2$ diverges (plus additional condition). This is out of the scope of my answer, no?

Comment: Well the link I posted is precisely giving the (standardized) limit of partial sums, indeed for general r.v.'s but gaussian variables should pass this Theorem too. In any case, I trust the characteristic function approach so there's nothing more to check :)

Comment: The link you posted asks also that $\max\{\sigma_k^2;k\leqslant n\}\ll\sum\limits_{i\leqslant n}\sigma_i^2$, which cannot happen when the series $\sum\limits_n\sigma_n^2$ converges.

Comment: @Martingalo Sorry, I posted two comments answering yours without signaling them by @.

Comment: Many thanks to all! ;)

Comment: @Did We can relax the independence requirement of all $X_k$ if they are jointly normal, can we not?  Wikipedia cites p.35 of Lemons, Don S. (2002), _An Introduction to Stochastic Processes in Physics_ for this result.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider the sequence $\{S_n\}$ of finite partial sums: $\displaystyle S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. As you state, this is a sequence of normal random variables, each distributed as 
$$
S_n\sim\mathcal{N}\left(m_n,s_n^2\right)
$$
where $\displaystyle m_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\mu_k$ and $\displaystyle s_n^2=\sum^n_{k=1}\sigma_k^2$. Now the question is: does $S_n$ converge in some suitable sense to $\displaystyle S\sim\mathcal{N}\left(m,s^2\right)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, given $\displaystyle m=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}m_n$ and $\displaystyle s^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n^2$ exist?

For the "suitable sense" of convergence, let us use the convergence in distribution. This kind of convergence means that the cumulative distribution function (CDF) converges to the limiting CDF, pointwise, wherever the limiting CDF is continuous. Since the limiting distribution is normal, it is continuous everywhere. There is also a result known as Scheffe's lemma that implies that if the probability density functions (PDFs) converge, this implies convergence in distribution as well. So this is what we'll test: does the sequence of PDFs converge to the limiting PDF? Let $f_n(x)$ be the sequence of PDFs for the $S_n$ variables
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{s_n\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-m_n)^2}{2s_n^2}\right)
$$
To finish off a proof, you have to show that
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x) = \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2s^2}\right)
$$
Intuitively, I know this is to be true because this sequence of functions doesn't do one of those "nasty" things like become infinitely thin in places; for one, $s_n$ controls the width of these things, and that is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and bounded. But, I'd have to brush up on my real analysis a bit to coherently argue for this.

In any case, if you can show that limit is correct rigorously, you'll have shown that the PDF of the sequence converges, so the sequence converges in probability to the one you conjectured.

Comment: Why bother with densities when easier tools such as characteristic functions are available?

Comment: Honestly, it is just what I immediately thought of using. The Levy theorem you proposed using didn't come to mind. But if I'm not mistaken, the sequence of characteristic functions would look no simpler than the sequence of densities, no?

Comment: No big deal, and no big difference anyway--but look at the caveats you have to sparse your answer with, and compare them with the (basically) one-line answer Lévy allows.

Comment: Yes, my approach does seem inelegant by comparison. I guess that's why I haven't gotten to 145k rep yet :-)

Comment: @rajb245 I also liked your answer. Many thanks. ;)